# Chart js stacking issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

[image: Current status]

I have created a Chart, there wasn't problem, but recently I needed to make 3 bars, stacking by x and y axis. But it was impossible to make it as I want, so I created new issue in github.
[github issue link](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11556)

And then I tried to find a new solution.
As you can see screenshot, I tried to separate 3 round bars into 2 parts. At start it seems it's working fine, but it was impossible to make square bar to round bar.

Please let me know the solution.

```
ChartJS.defaults.borderColor = 'transparent';
ChartJS.defaults.elements.bar.borderRadius = 50;
ChartJS.defaults.elements.bar.borderSkipped = false;

    setChartOptions({
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'top',
          labels: {
            boxWidth: 10,
            boxHeight: 10,
            useBorderRadius: true,
            borderRadius: 5,
            textAlign: 'right',
          },
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Chart',
        },
        tooltip: {
          // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
          // enabled: true,
          enabled: false,

          external: (context) => {
            if (!currentRoot) {
              return;
            }
            currentRoot.render(
              <ChartTooltip
                dict={dict}
                context={context}
                onlyPositive
              />,
            );
          },
        },
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          time: {
            unit: 'hour',
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'H:mm',
            },
          },
          ticks: {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
            callback: (value, index) => {
              switch (selectedRange) {
                case TimeRange.Today:
                  if (index % 4 === 0) {
                    return DateFNS.format(
                      new Date(value),
                      index === 0 ? 'H:mm' : 'k:mm',
                    );
                  }
                  return '';
                case TimeRange.Week:
                  return DateFNS.format(new Date(value), 'E');
                case TimeRange.Month:
                  return DateFNS.format(new Date(value), 'd');
                case TimeRange.Year:
                  return DateFNS.format(new Date(value), 'LLL');
                  return '';
              }
            },
            sampleSize: 1,
            autoSkip: false,
            source: 'labels',
          },
          stacked: true,
          alignToPixels: true,
        },
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stacked: true,
          grid: {
            drawTicks: false,
          },
          ticks: {
            callback: (value) => {
              if (typeof value === 'string') {
                return value;
              }
              return value < 0 ? -value : value;
            },
          },
          border: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Make square bar to round bar.